# How to run a bash script as a command?

Tags: bash, global, alias

I have a bash script that I would like to run globally as a command. For that I moved the script to `/usr/local/bin/somefile.sh`.

Now I still have to call a command called `somefile.sh`. I would like to have an alias for this command (for example I would just like to call the script with the command `sf`).

How do I do that?

Comment: Easiest solution, rename it to `sf`.

Comment: I already used the aliases. Would it still execute, if it is no longer an `.sh` file? If it has not file ending?

Comment: Yes. In fact, [it's generally recommended *not* to give scripts a `.sh` extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503127/should-i-save-my-scripts-with-the-sh-extension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And to complement answer from @Kent :

`alias sf='/usr/local/bin/somefile.sh'` using alias

`ln -s somefile.sh /usr/local/bin/sf`  using soft link

`mv /usr/local/bin/somefile.sh /usr/local/bin/sf` using renaming

Comment: Is there a way to make the definition of the alias permanent. I don`t want to retype it after every restart of my computer.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways:

- as you mentioned, use `alias`,  `man alias` for details
- create a soft link named `sf` to your real script
- rename your script

Comment: Is there a way to make the definition of the alias permanent. I don`t want to retype it after every restart of my computer.

Comment: @User12547645 add the alias to .bashrc file.

Answer (score 2):

Open your `.bashrc` file located in `~/.bashrc`. `.bashrc` file is read whenever you login to the system. Add the below line to the end of the file.

`alias sf='/usr/local/bin/somefile.sh'`

then re login or run `source .bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a GNU system, you could use the "alternatives" system:

```
dir=/usr/local/bin
sudo update-alternatives --install $dir/sf somefile $dir/somefile.sh 10
```

This creates 2 symbolic links:

```
/usr/local/bin/sf -> /etc/alternatives/somefile
/etc/alternatives/somefile -> /usr/local/bin/somefile.sh
```